# Generating a hex file(new to ubuntu)

Tags: gcc

How am I supposed to compile/generate a .hex file (object code) of a c program using a gcc compiler?.
Will the procedure be the same for a different gcc compiler compatible with a different processor?

Comment: Have you used gcc before on e.g. windows or a mac?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this here ? :

gcc -c example.c

objcopy --change-address 0xE0000 -O ihex example.o example.hex

Comment: Will this command apply to any other gcc compiler?.For eg: I have installed a gcc compiler that is compatible with some xyz processor.Will this same command generate the corresponding object code?